# My list shows as a nontype and I have no idea why

Tags: python, class, oop

When I created a child class and added a function that uses a list the list shows as a nontype:

class restaurant:
"""An attempt at a class for a restaurant"""

```
def __init__(self, resaurant_name, cuisine_type):
    """Attributes distribution"""

    self.name = resaurant_name
    self.cuisine = cuisine_type
    self.number_served = 0

#Extension for number of orders
def set_number_served(self, numbers):
    """Setting for number of served orders"""

    self.number_served = numbers

#Increment for served orders
def increment_number_served(self, more_yummy):
    """Increment for served orders"""

    self.number_served += more_yummy

def describe_restaurant(self):
    """Description about restaurant"""

    print(f"The restaurant's name is {self.name.title()}")
    print(f"The cuisine type is {self.cuisine.title()}")

def open_restaurant(self):
    """The restaurant is now open!"""

    print(f"{self.name.title()} is now open!")
```

#Child class
class ice_cream_stand(restaurant):

```
def __init__(self, restaurant_name, cuisine_type, flavors = ["Chocolate", "Vanilla", "Rainbow", "Sponge Bob"]):

    """Inheritance from parent class"""
    super().__init__(restaurant_name, cuisine_type)
    
    self.flavors = flavors

def list_flavors(self):
    print("We have these flavors available: ")
    for flavor in self.flavors:
        print(f"- {flavor}")
```

IceCreamStand = ice_cream_stand("La Michoacana", "Ice LoL")
print(IceCreamStand.list_flavors())

I printed out the function as was only expecting the list to be printed, but it also showed me it was a nontype.

It showed like this:
**Output**:
We have these flavors available:
-Chocolate
-Vanilla
-Rainbow
-Sponge Bob
-None

Answer (score 0):

Just `IceCreamStand.list_flavors()` is enough as the function already prints the flavors. When you do `print(IceCreamStand.list_flavors())` it prints the return from `IceCreamStand.list_flavors()` which in your case is nothing aka `None`

Answer (score 0):

When you don't return anything from a python function, `None` is returned by default. Here you're printing the flavors inside the class method `list_flavors` and returning nothing. So the print statement will print `None`.

To avoid this issue, either call the method without the print function or return the list from the `list_flavors` method and print it outside the method.